# Solve equation with unknown number of Matlab sym variables

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I am writing Matlab code to solve equations with an unknown number of `sym` variables. The number of variables supplied by the user. Here is code for three `sym` variables, but the code produces an error.

```
clc;
clear
format long;
m=3;
mv = sym(zeros(m, 1));
for k=1:m
    mv(k,1) = sym(sprintf('m%d', k));
end
display(mv)
A=[  1.000   2.000   3.000     
 2.000  -2.000  -3.000     
  3.000   -3.000   7.000    
];
B=[1;0;5];
w=A*mv-B
s=solve(w==0)
F=s.mv;
display(F)
```

This is not different from solving a simple equation with `solve`.

Comment: Please share the error message you receive and on what line you get it.

Comment: Reference to non-existent field 'mv'.

Error in test (line 17)
F=[s.mv]

Comment: You probably have a bunch of variables: `s.m1`, `s.m2`, etc.

Comment: yes but i don know how to get like this:

Comment: You probably want `for k=1:m, mv(k,1)=s.(sprintf('m%d',k)); end` after the `solve`, then use `F=mv;` as you intended to. OR: `F=struct2cell(s); F=[F{:}].';`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andras Deak. i get the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `solve` for a linear problem like this. [`sym/linsolve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/linsolve.html) would be a much better choice, doesn't require creating additional variables, and returns the solution as a vector:

```
A = sym([1.000   2.000   3.000     
         2.000  -2.000  -3.000     
         3.000  -3.000   7.000    
        ]);
B = sym([1;0;5]);
s = linsolve(A,B)
```

returns

```
s =

    1/3
 -22/69
  10/23
```

Note that if you don't explicitly convert `A` and/or `B` to a symbolic array the numeric version of [`linsolve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linsolve.html) will be used and the solution will be returned in floating point.

If you really want to use `solve`, your `for` loop is unnecessary as simple call to `sym` can be used:

```
m = 3;
mv = sym('m',[m 1])
A = sym([1.000   2.000   3.000     
         2.000  -2.000  -3.000     
         3.000  -3.000   7.000    
        ]);
B = sym([1;0;5]);
w = A*mv-B;
s = struct2cell(solve(w==0))
s = [s{:}].'
```

In both case you can use `vpa` and/or `double` to convert the solutions to a numeric format.

Comment: my problem is not explicit, it is finite element problem that unknowns variable is in both side of equation, for example like this : K*U=F that for example 3 unknown is in the U and 3 unknown is in the F and K is 6*6,i don't know how to solve this form of equation

Comment: @masih please tell me you don't want to solve a finite-element problem using symbolic math. Please. Don't. Do. That.

Comment: so what should i do??

Comment: @masih: I answered what was posed in your question. I can't guess your actual problem, only what is in your question. As far as I can tell, `sym/linsolve` should be fine for a simple 6-by-6 system even if you have free variables on the left and right (if not, try `solve` as you're currently doing).

Comment: @masih do it numerically:) Using the native matlab environment, and not the symbolic engine. Your current question can be easily solved, but you've already hinted that your actual probem is more difficult. You might want to ask a new question regarding your actual question, but for that you should first look around the web to see what your options are, and try to implement a solution yourself.

Comment: first i write code for solve equation by changing the assemble matrix and in assemble matrix i set zero for row and column of assemble matrix in row of u that is unknown like this:for i=1:m
assemble(u(i),:)=0; 
assemble(:,u(i))=0;
assemble(u(i),u(i))=1;
 end
and use assemble^-1*F
but in my problem i have constraint for example u(2)=2 so i use solve

Comment: thanks a lot. i used solve method for my project and get a good answer.